# How to define a BuildConfig field for all modules of a project (gradle KTS)?

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Is there any way I can create a BuildConfig field for all my modules through the project's `build.gradle.kts` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. I just found a way on how to do that.

```
// build.gradle.kts (of the project)

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        (extensions.findByName("android") as? BaseExtension)?.apply {
            defaultConfig {
                buildConfigField("String", "base_url", "\"my.base.url\"")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is weird. Why the need of `(extensions.findByName("android") as? BaseExtension)` ? Also, why isn't it in the `buildTypes` part anymore? How do I reach the "base_url" that you've created? I can't find it in the generated BuildConfig class....